# ScreenToWorldPoint implementation ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to implement the `ScreenToWorldPoint` from Unity3D in threeJS.
Basically it transform a `screen point` into a `world point` at a given distance.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

In unity, given a perspective Camera with these settings.

```
//fov,ratio,near,far
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 411 / 731, 0.3, 1000)
```

And these parameters

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, -16))
```

In unity3D I get this vector which is expected `(5.2, 9.2, -32.0)`

But in my implementation I'm not managing to get the same vector.
This is my implementation.

```
function screenToWorldPoint(screenSpaceCoord, target = new THREE.Vector3()) {

  const ndc = new THREE.Vector2();
  ndc.x = (2 * screenSpaceCoord.x) / 411 - 1;
  ndc.y = 1 - (2 * screenSpaceCoord.y) / 731;

  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera(ndc, camera);

  return raycaster.ray.at(screenSpaceCoord.z, new THREE.Vector3());
}
```

Comment: What position and rotation of your camera?

Comment: You also want to use [Vector3.unproject()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.unproject).